# AngularJS $compiled elements aren't added to form which they reside inside of.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I would like element strings with form properties that are `$compiled` onto a template to be added directly to the form they are compiled into, (via DOM inheritance) but from testing—it doesn't happen automatically. It would be nice if this happened so that I could then validate the form, including the newly compiled elements that have form attributes.

JS

```
.directive('addDynamicFormElements', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
      var tmpl = "<input name='newFormItem' ng-model='formScope.item3' required>";
      scope.click = function () {
        var el = angular.element(document.querySelector('#addFieldHere'));
        var compiled = $compile(tmpl)(scope);
        el.append(compiled);
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

HTML

```
<h1>My Form</h1>
 <div ng-form="myForm">
    <input name="first" ng-model="formScope.item1">
    <input name="second" ng-model="formScope.item2">
    <button add-dynamic-form-elements ng-click="click()">Click here to append a new field</button>
    <div id="addFieldHere"></div>
 </div>
```

Here is a PLNKR, where by binding the form expression to the template you can clearly see that the form does not directly include the new compiled element: http://plnkr.co/edit/Blogc4lSVyNd26ySwGlq?p=preview

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you may know, `$compile` returns a link function. That link function returns the already-linked element. This element has not yet been put inside the DOM, so in its linking phase it is unaware of the form it is supposed to be in.

Two way to solve this:

**#1: use `cloneAttachFn` function**:

```
link: function(scope, element){

  var tmpl = "<input name='newFormItem' ng-model='formScope.item3' required>";

  $compile(tmpl)(scope, function cloneAttachFn(prelinkedClone){
    element.append(prelinkedClone);
  });
}
```

**#2: append to the element to the DOM prior to compile/link**:

```
link: function(scope, element){

  var tmpl = "<input name='newFormItem' ng-model='formScope.item3' required>";
  var templateElement = angular.element(tmpl);

  element.append(templateElement);
  $compile(templateElement)(scope);
}
```

Comment: It looks like #1 is deprecated (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile ) so I'll go with #2. Thanks!

Comment: @nikkwong, it's the transclude in the `$compile` function that is deprecated - not the `cloneAttachFn` parameter of the `link` function. Take a look at the "return value" - a function with a `cloneAttachFn` parameter, not the deprecated parameter of `$compile`: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#usage... So, #1 is very valid and preferred approach

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually add the to form

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) { 
  $scope.formScope = {};
})
.directive('addDynamicFormElements', ['$compile', function($compile) {
  return {
   require: ['?^^form', 'ngModel'],
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs,ctrls) {
      var form=ctrls[0];
      var inputCtrl=ctrls[1];
      var tmpl = "<input name='newFormItem'  required>";
      scope.click = function () {
        var el = angular.element(document.querySelector('#addFieldHere'));
        console.log(form);
        form["newFormItem"] = inputCtrl;
        var compiled = $compile(tmpl)(scope);
        el.append(compiled);
      }
    }
  }
}]);
```

Made changes to your code..check it out

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y3WCBVq7DyluaJBY1EOp?p=preview

Comment: Seems perfectly valid and acceptable to me. Voted up.

Comment: Try adding a new form field, type something in, and check if `myForm.$dirty` is true. It would still be `false`, but not so for preexisting fields. So, this approach tries to imitate *some* of what a proper registration with a form is doing, but not all. You should do `form.$addControl(inputCtrl)`, instead of `form["newFormItem"]`. So, this works for a limited case of a `form` control, but wouldn't work for a more generic case. / @nikkwon

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to bind elements with angular scope from JS and angular

```js
function myCtrl($scope,$compile) {
$scope.test="Hello World";
$scope.heooli=false;
    $scope.AppendText = function() {
     $('#divID').append('<p>{{test}}</p>');
     var myEl = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#divID' ) );
     $compile(myEl)($scope);
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<body>
<button ng-click="AppendText()">
  Append
</button>
<p ng-show="heooli">Test</p>
<input type="text" ng-model="test">
<div id="divID">
</div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```